# Problem With Angular project's URL running in an Apache server

Tags: angular, url, routes

Look, i don't know if I expressed myself well in the title but here it goes.

I made a angular app that the clients can buy plans of a gym through my website. So i made a route scheme that the first thing in the URL is the Gym's id(recovered from my data base) then "/plans".

Ex: `localhost:4200/000162/plans`

Here comes the problem, i made a build of my project and the folder structure is something like `dist/__projectName__/__projectContent__`.

With the command `ng build --prod --base-href /vysor_vendas_online/app/`

Then i put it all the projectContent in my Apache server folder in the path `www/vysor_vendas_online/app/` and tried to run in my browser.

`localhost:8080/vysor_vendas_online/app/index.html?000162/plans` but nothing happens, it stays in a white screen with no console errors, but when i try with Angular server `localhost:4200/000162/plans` it works.

What am i doing wrong here? How should i access the routes that i specified in my code?

Answer (score 0):

as the official [deployment](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml) doc said

> Routed apps must fallback to index.html

Apache: add a rewrite rule to the .htaccess file as shown (https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/03/09/angularjs-html5-mode-or-pretty-urls-on-apache-using-htaccess/):

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Comment: Only by editing my .htaccess file i should be able to pass the paramters after the `index.html?` ??

Like this `localhost:8080/vysor_vendas_online/app/index.html?000162/plans`

Comment: params and other routing staff handled by angular router. but as a prerequisites you have to config apache by using .htaccess to fallback your requests to index.html of angular.

Comment: Ow, ok, i will try and comeback with the results. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Same thing :(, i added `RewriteEngine On` in the .htaccess file. Tried then:

`localhost:8080/vysor_vendas_online/app/index.html?000162/planos`

Then: 

Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'index.html' - 
Angular error, then i removed the "index.html", like this:

`localhost:8080/vysor_vendas_online/app?000162/planos`

Still nothing, am i doing somethig wrong?